# Why is this question closed (_and_ locked)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

["Comments are a code smell"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1/comments-are-a-code-smell)

From the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), I would expect it to fall under the "good" topic of Software Engineering, and from [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), it seems to meet almost all the criteria for "Good Subjective":

- Not only to the answers posted all agree, they also all explain *why*.
- Most answers are medium-length, not short.
- Most of the upvoted ones are impartial (that second one, not so much).
- On the other hand, that second one falls under this criteria - it shares an experience to explain *why*.
- There are references in some of the less-upvoted answers.
- This one in particular seems to have hit a nerve - it's most definitely not "mindless social fun".

*And* there's the massive amount of upvotes both the question and answers have, so it was definitely a question users liked.  (I'm still using it as a reference *because* of the high-quality answers and examples!)

So... Shouldn't this be an open question on this site?  It seems like *exactly* the type of thing [we should be encouraging](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/are-you-still-confused-about-what-programmers-is-for).  (Perhaps, just edit the question's "What do you think?" and change it to "Is he right?")

Comment: _"just edit"_ - this idea has been discussed in depth a while ago at MSO: [Suggestions for editing old “Not constructive” question into constructiveness so that it can be preserved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141006/165773)

Comment: "I'm still using it as a reference because of the high-quality answers and examples!" And that's _exactly_ the reason I locked it, to protect it from deletion. The question qualifies for a historical lock because a) it's not a good question, b) but _some_ of the answers are great and c) it has _a lot_ of inbound links. I'm not so sure why you think we should be encouraging such questions, quite the opposite really, open ended, overly broad and ill defined questions are not what the site is about. The fact that it got a few awesome answers doesn't make it a better question unfortunately...

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to mention the 20 or so answers that are not very good answers; they fail "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" tests 1,2,4 and 5 for the most part.  Thats' a pretty good indication that the question itself is "not constructive."

Closing and locking means that the question is already adequately answered, we're not accepting any more answers, and the post is protected from deletion.  I'd say that post is a perfect candidate.

Comment: The vast majority of those "me, too" answers are by users that are low-rep even now; it may well have been their first posts on this site.  If it existed back then, the correct course of action would've been to put that new user protection on the question (where you need some amount of rep to post an answer).

Comment: Does the question ***really*** need more answers, from anyone?

Comment: So you advocate locking all questions that have an accepted answer?

Comment: They were new users; the answer should've been downvoted and explained to them why an additional answer was not necessary

Comment: `So you advocate locking all questions that have an accepted answer?` -- That's a straw man.  Do you have any questions for me that are not straw men?

Comment: `They were new users; the answer should've been downvoted and explained to them why an additional answer was not necessary` -- Or, we can just lock the question and be done with it.

Comment: It is not a straw man because _you said it yourself_:  `Closing and locking means that the question is already adequately answered, we're not accepting any more answers, and the post is protected from deletion`.  So why not just do it to all questions with accepted answers?

Comment: @Izkata: You didn't answer my prior question.  Does this post ***really*** need more input from anyone else?  Locking prevents posts from being updated, so it's only done on posts where there's clearly nothing of substantial value that anyone can add.

Comment: Who decides whether or not a question warrants any further activity? Apparently, like so many things on this site, that decision has been taken away from the community and now lies with a few individuals.

Comment: @MattDavey: Well, I hope we can both agree that the question is not a very good one.  Consequently the focus shifts from keeping the question open (which is hopeless) to preserving it (protecting it from eventual deletion).  The question would be a much better one if it asked about where and when comments should be used (almost certainly a duplicate of some other question), rather than the flame bait and bikeshedding bait that it currently is.